# Regex.Split adding empty strings to result array

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex to split out words operators and brackets in simple logic statements (e.g. "WORD1 & WORD2 | (WORd_3 & !word_4 )".  the Regex I've come up with is "(?[A-Za-z0-9_]+)|(?[&!\|()]{1})".  Here is a quick test program.

---

```
using System; 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
        Console.WriteLine("* Test Project *"); 
        string testExpression = "!(LIONV6 | NOT_superCHARGED) &RHD"; 
        string removedSpaces = testExpression.Replace(" ", ""); 
        string[] expectedResults = new string[] { "!", "(", "LIONV6", "|", "NOT_superCHARGED", ")", "&", "RHD" }; 
        string[] splits = Regex.Split(removedSpaces, @"(?[A-Za-z0-9_]+)|(?[&!\|()]{1})");

        Console.WriteLine("Expected\n{0}\nActual\n{1}", expectedResults.AllElements(), splits.AllElements());

        Console.WriteLine("*** Any Key to finish ***");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string AllElements(this string[] str)
    {
        string output = "";
        if (str != null)
        {
            foreach (string item in str)
            {
                output += "'" + item + "',";
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

---

The Regex does the required job of splitting out words and operators into an array in the right sequence, but the result array contains many empty elements, and I can't work out why.  Its not a serious problem as I just ignore empty elements when consuming the array but I'd like Regex to do all the work if possible, including ignoring spaces.

Comment: Where are you expecting the spaces in the input string to go? You don't have them in your expected array but I can't see where you are getting rid of them anywhere...

Comment: @Chris there are no spaces, he used testExpression.Replace(" ", "");

Comment: @DorCohen: Ah, I did wonder if I was being dense. Seems I was. ;-)

Comment: It would be good if the Regex could ignore spaces as well as eliminating the empty strings, so I don;t have to do the Replace()

Comment: @TomBrown: You are slightly abusing `Split` here since what you are really trying to do is match things. `Matches` gets around the space issue because it is using purely positive matches and ignoring the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(removedSpaces, @"(\w+|[&!|()])");

foreach (var match in matches)
    Console.Write("'{0}', ", match); // '!', '(', 'LIONV6', '|', 'NOT_superCHARGED', ')', '&', 'RHD',
```

Actually, you don't need to delete spaces before extracting your identifiers and operators, the regex I proposed will ignore them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string[] splits = Regex.Split(removedSpaces, @"(?[A-Za-z0-9_]+)|(?[&!\|()]{1})").Where(x => x != String.Empty);
```

Comment: upvoted for Good lateral thinking, but Regex isn't actually doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces are jsut becasue of the way the split works. From the [help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx):

> If multiple matches are adjacent to one another, an empty string is inserted into the array.

What split is doing as standard is taking your matches as delimiters. So in effect the standard that would be returned is a lot of empty strings between the adjacent matches (imagine as a comparison what you might expect if you split `",,,,"` on `","`, you'd probably expect all the gaps.

Also from that help page though is:

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any
>   captured text is included in the resulting string array.

This is the reason you are getting what you actually want in there at all. So effectively it is now showing you the text that has been split (all the empty strings) with the delimiters too.

What you are doing may well be better off done with just matching the regular expression (with [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx)) since what is in your regular expression is actually what you want to match.

Something like this (using some linq to convert to a string array):

```
Regex.Matches(testExpression, @"([A-Za-z0-9_]+)|([&!\|()]{1})")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(x=>x.Value)
     .ToArray();
```

Note that because this is taking positive matches it doesn't need the spaces to be removed first.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation. I've gone with the Matches idea.